# Making a linked list from command line arguments

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, command-line-arguments

I have to make a linked list from arguments entered from the command line. You are supposed to enter integers and make a linked list out of them. When you enter -1, then stop reading from the command line. Fairly simple, but I am having some trouble. What I have is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int grade;
  struct node *next;
};

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct node *root;
  root = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
  root->next = 0;
  root->grade = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
      if (&argv[i] == -1)
        {
          break;
        }
      else
        {
          struct node *new_item_ptr;
          new_item_ptr = malloc (sizeof (struct node));
          new_item_ptr->grade = (*int) argv[i];
          (*new_item_ptr).next = root;
          root = new_item_ptr;
        }
    }
}
```

I think I'm pretty close, but there are a few things that doesn't work correctly. For example, I don't think `for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)` is correct. And the compiler says that `new_item_ptr->grade = (*int) argv[i];` is wrong also. Can anyone help me out with this? I think I'm close just have a few minor errors.

Answer (score 2):

The various `argv[i]`s are C-strings (char*) not integers.  You need to convert them to integers, and the best way to do that is with the `atoi` function:

```
int value = atoi(argv[i]);
if (value == -1) {
    break;
} else {
    // etc.
}
```

The function name `atoi` is supposed to be a mnemonic for "ASCII to integer."  The syntax you're using to assign the `next` field of `new_item_ptr` is a little more complicated than it needs to be as well.  You can use the arrow syntax to assign the `next` field just as you did to assign the `grade` field.  This part should look like:

```
new_item_ptr->grade = atoi(argv[i]);
new_item_ptr->next = root;
```

Or, better still, re-use the `value` variable created at the top of this iteration of the for loop instead of running `atoi` again:

```
new_item_ptr->grade = value;
new_item_ptr->next = root;
```

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, you have `malloc`'ed a structure which is totally unnecessary.  If the user enters no data, you can return an empty list indicated by `root = NULL`.  So, the initial part could be:

```
root = ( struct node * ) NULL;
if ( argc < 2 )
    return ( 0 );
```

As your code stands, the first node will always have 0 for `root->grade`.  In the loop, you should allocate the memory and convert the `argv[i]` to integer using `atoi`.  Finally, your loop should start with `i=1` because `argv[0]` is the command name itself.

Comment: +1 for the for loop starting at 1 not 0.  I missed that part.  I suppose OP would have noticed it pretty quickly as soon as the program was expanded to print the linked list.  All those `malloc`s should be `free`d eventually too, but I maybe deallocating the linked list is outside the scope of the original question.